# Change the position of the cursor in a git commit template

Tags: git, vim, githooks

I'm currently using a git commit template (stored in a file) and a prepare-commit-msg hook to replace a placeholder in the commit template with the current branch name (that is actually is the identifier of the story in our bug tracking of choice). The output of this process is opened in VIM.

My commit message will start with [story_identifier]; is there a way to place the VIM cursor after this identifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the following command should position the cursor as you want (from the first line, search for the `[story_identifier]` and go to the character after it):

```
:1|execute "normal! /\[story_identifier\]/e+1\<CR>"
```

Now, there are two ways to make Vim execute this when opening a Git commit message:

Configure Git to pass this to Vim when launching it. e.g. via

```
git config core.editor 'vim +...'
```

The challenge here is proper escaping :-) Or, you could hook into Vim's *filetype detection*:

```
:autocmd FileType gitcommit 1|execute "normal! /\[story_identifier\]/e+1\<CR>"
```

Comment: Instead of using `:execute` and `:normal`, I would use `1call search('\[story_identifier]', 'ce')`.  See `:help search()`.

Comment: @benjifisher: Yep, that would work, too. Depends on whether you want to seed the last search register (e.g. to jump to following identifiers with `n`).

Comment: I prefer the first solution since I want this only for a project or two. As you said I'm struggling with the escaping but I will eventually figuring out