# Open Git commit editor to specific cursor location

Tags: git, vim

I have modified my `prepare-commit-msg` hook to include the branch name at the beginning of my commit message (e.g. `[JCH-234] -`).  However, when I run `git commit` the cursor is located at the beginning of the editor `Vim`.  I'm looking for a way to start the cursor at the location following my branch name.

I'm aware that it's only a few extra key strokes to move the cursor however, I believe in attention to detail and would like to implement this if possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the position of the cursor in a git commit template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22632848/change-the-position-of-the-cursor-in-a-git-commit-template)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IMO, this is git config thing, we shouldn't add special vim script/config for it.

You can set `GIT_EDITOR` variable like:

```
GIT_EDITOR="vim -c'startinsert|norm! ggA'"
```

This makes everytime you git commit, git will hook your pre-commit-msg, then open vim, put cursor at the end of the first line, in your case, after your branch name, also switch to insert mode.

Comment: This works.  However, I'm just wondering, is there a case where I wouldn't want the Git editor to open with the cursor at the end of the line?  The only other time I can think of when Git uses the editor is an interactive rebase and I don't think this would be a problem.  Thoughts?

Comment: @JakeHenningsgaard no matter where do you want to put the cursor after vim opens, you can change the `-c'...'` command with your vim-fu. E.g. after one word, `...|norm! w` ...

Comment: @JakeHenningsgaard also since you have already opened vim, moving cursor in vim is just on your finger tip. it would be very easy right? if it is as you said, only some time you don't want to put it at EOL.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.  I was thinking that there might be a case where a want to have the cursor at the end of line when running `git commit` BUT when running `git rebase -i` I may want it at the beginning of the line.  I don't think this is the case nor do I think this applies but, I just thought I'd ask.

Comment: But why does the cursor start at lower than usual?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
augroup git_commit
    autocmd!

    autocmd BufReadPost *
        \  if &filetype == 'gitcommit'
        \|     execute 'normal $'
        \| endif
augroup end
```

The [`BufReadPost`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#BufReadPost) autocommand is fired after the contents of the buffer are loaded. If the `filetype` is `gitcommit` we can run any motion to move the cursor.

Here I used `$` to move to the end of the line, but you could also use `f-` or something else that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using vim as your editor use the "A" (capital A) command to enter insert mode at the end of the line.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I am using Vim.  This solution won't work.  I need Vim to open with the cursor at a specific location.  The point is I want to avoid having to move the cursor every time I do a `git commit`.

Comment: You want to write a commit message after the feature tag, don't you? If so, then this solution works, I use it myself in my daily workflow. When pressing "A" in NORMAL mode, vim will move the cursor to the end of the line and then enter INSERT mode. Then you can write your message, leave INSERT mode, save and the commit is finished. You do not have to move the cursor at all.